# Is it possible to chain a jQuery object to a custom object method?

Tags: jquery, chaining

I'm wondering how I could use a syntax like `$(someSelector).someObj.someMethod()` in conjunction with jQuery?

The Idea: I don't want to extend `$.fn` with a bunch of custom functions. Therefore `someObj` contains several methods which should resolve `this` to `$(someSelector)`.

I know that I could use just [one custom function which execudes code depending on its argument](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#minimizing-plugin-footprint):

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.customFunc = function( funcSelector ) {
        if ( funcSelector === "do this") {
            // do this
        }
        if ( funcSelector === "do that" ) {
            // do that
        }
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

So `$(someSelector).customFunc(funcSelector)` is a good workaround.

But I'm still curious: **Is it possible to achieve chainability between jQuery and custom objects?**

**Update #1:**

I like @jfriend00's approach. See his last edit. It's also based on passing the custom function name as string parameter BUT it allows defining custom functions as real functions, not some code wrapped in an if/switch statement.

**Update #2:**

See @barmar's custom class approach in the answers.

Comment: Yes, you just have to extend `$.fn`. Which is essentially what a jQuery plugin does. So `jQuery.fn.extend({someMethod: function(){//your code here}})`

Comment: I don't think it is possible... because when you call `$(someSelector).someObj.someMethod()` the execution context for `someMethod` will be `someObj`, not the jQuery object

Comment: is there any particular reason why you don't want to extend `$.fn`

Comment: @ArunPJohny good catch. But it is possible. Just not with chaining. You would just use `call` or `apply`. `someObj.someMethod.call($(someSelector))`

Comment: @AdamMerrifield yes.. that is possible.. but does not looks like a good solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny Not alone. But what about extending `$.fn` to call the function? `jQuery.fn.extend({someMethod: function(){return someObj.someMethod.call($(this));}});`

Comment: @AdamMerrifield yes... but from what I understand from the post, OP doesn't want to do that :(

Comment: I have no problem with extending `$.fn`. I just don't want to extend the prototype with more than one method. :) The linked solution is okay for me. I'm just uncertain if there's no better way to wrap my custom functions.

Comment: You could have your custom jQuery method return an object of your own class, instead of a jQuery object. Then you define your methods in that class. It can include the original jQuery object as a property, and return that so that you can chain jQuery methods to it.

Comment: As I mention in my answer, there's no difference in namespace collision between `x.someObj.someMethod` and `x.someObj_someMethod` so you can just use a common and unique prefix on all your methods and not have the `this` problem or run any more namespace collision risk than necessary.

Comment: Yepp, prefixes are another solution but I think they uglify your code. jfriend00's last addition looks promising though, same for Barmar's suggestion. I'll give them a try and report back.

Comment: You have a prefix either way, the only difference is "_" vs. ".".  If you think about it that way, I don't see how one is uglified vs. the other.  You can even skip the underscore if you want.

Comment: Hm, good argument, @jfriend00. Looks like the string parameter version is the most readable solution IMO. Though I still need to check out yours and Barmar's alternatives.

Comment: Hey, @Barmar! Did I implement your suggestion the right way? The call works like this: `$(someSelector).someObj().someMethod()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$(someSelector).someObj.someMethod()
```

by adding a property `someObj` to `jQuery.fn` that is an object with it's own methods including `someObj`.

```
jQuery.fn.someObj = {
    someMethod: function() {
        // method code here
    }
};
```

But, when you do that and call it like you specified as `$(someSelector).someObj.someMethod()`, the `this` value in `.someMethod()` will be `someObj` and will NOT be the jQuery object so this is generally not a useful thing to do because you lose access to the jQuery object which is generally the reason for adding jQuery methods.

---

If you're concerned about adding too many methods to the jQuery namespace, then you can just use your own prefix on the method names and it will be insignificantly different from what you were asking for originally from a namespace collision point of view (this just uses a `_` between parts of a single name instead of `.` between two names:

```
$(someSelector).myUniquePrefix_add();
$(someSelector).myUniquePrefix_remove();
$(someSelector).myUniquePrefix_modify();
```

---

Any work-arounds that attempt to solve the `this` issue in the first scheme are messy at best and simply not worth the trouble or the overhead because Javascript just doesn't work that way.

For example, you could make it work like this:

```
jQuery.fn.someObj = function(method /* other args */) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return this.someObj[method].apply(this, args);
}

jQuery.fn.someObj.someMethod = function() {
    // method code here
}

// and then call it like this
$(someSelector).someObj("someMethod", "arg1", "arg2");
```

Comment: I think this is what he's already doing, and he discovered that he lost access to the jQuery object. The whole point of his question is whether it's possible to solve that, which it probably isn't.

Comment: @Barmar - I didn't read the question that way, but I've added some more info in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer, @jfriend00! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here's the code implementing @Barmar's suggestion:

```
// declare wrapper class for custom functions
function Custom() {}
// define custom functions as object methods
Custom.prototype.doThis = function() {
// do something with this.jObj
    return this.jObj;
}
Custom.prototype.doThat = function() {
    // do something with this.jObj
    return this.jObj;
}
// use jQuery's custom function interface to initialize wrapper object
$.fn.custom = function() {
    var custom = new Custom();
    custom.jObj = this;
    return custom;
};
// call your custom functions
$(selector).custom().doThis();
$(selector).custom().doThat();
```

I don't like the syntax of the call and therefore prefer @jfriend00's parameter-based solution, but if you're okay with the use of a pseudo method you have a nice wrapper class for your custom functions at hand.

**Edit:** Creating a Custom object on a custom() call (see @jfriend00's comment).

Comment: So, you're essentially using a global `custom.jObj` to temporarily store the value of the jQuery object - hoping that nobody else overwrites it before you need to use it.  That would work in some cases, would get into trouble in other cases and just generally feels like troublesome code to me.  If you created a `new Custom()` object each time `.custom()` was called, it would be more tolerable.

Comment: You're right. Asynchronous calls could be a problem when using just one wrapper object. Anyway, I don't support this solution either. I don't even know if the code above is what @Barmar had in mind. It's just what I put together according to his input.